# Не получается провести миграцию python.django

Tags: python-3.x, django, migrate

Программа makemigrations работает . Но при попытке запуска migrate возникает ошибка, указанная ниже.

Вот код python manage.py makemigrations:

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\itproger>python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'news':
  news\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Articles
```

Вот код python manage.py migrate:

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\itproger>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, news, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 42
1, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "django_content_type" already exists

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\itproger\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\itproger\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 41
9, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 41
3, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, i
n run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, i
n execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in
 wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
 line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117,
 in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147,
 in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227,
 in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 126
, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py",
line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 345
, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 145
, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in ex
ecute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in ex
ecute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _e
xecute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 42
1, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "django_content_type" already exists
```

Объясните в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

похоже что в БД уже все есть... Если ничего ценного в плане содержимого в БД пока нет, грохните базу и прогоните миграции для создания новой.

Если же что-то полезное есть и хотите сохранить, попробуйте:

> python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

более подробно тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial

Comment: терминале написал python manage.py migrate --fake-initial, заработало спасибо что помог.